Create Adobe SIgn API with `addressbook_read` scope enabled
We are using the new Adobe Sign Reusable recipient groups feature. Works great, thank you Adobe!
One problem, however. I seem to only be able to use the Adobe Sign GET /recipientGroups/{recipientGroupId} on the Adobe Sign REST documentation page. I don't seem to have a way to define a new OAuth application or generate an Integration Key with the addressbook_read scope enabled.
I've tried reaching out to Adobe Support. First level of support say "They are not developers" (face in my hand). Ticket was escalated but they are taking a very long time to respond. Has anyone been able to find a workaround to generate a refresh_token (or IntegrationKey) with this scope enabled?

If you're still not seeing this option in your tenant, all you need to do is open a ticket with Adobe Support and they will liaise with the "OPS Team" to enable the option within your tenant.
Note: You may receive some initial push back (like I did). Just ask that the ticket be escalated.
